# Solr wild card search with space in the middle

Tags: solr

Folks,

We want to do a solr wild card search with space in the middle.

e.g If we search for "Please\ Help*" then it should retrieve all the document which is having "Please Help" followed by documents which is having "Please" and "Help" words.

We see if we search "Please\ Help*" then it is only return document which is having "Please Help" and not returning search for individual tokens like "Please" and "help".

Given below is the field defination which we are using for indexing and search

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"> 
  <analyzer type="index">         
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
 </analyzer>  
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
  </analyzer>  
</fieldType>
```

Comment: try by removing the ShingleFilterFactory from the index and the query...

Comment: We cannot because we need to index for multiple word e.g for stream like "Please help here urgently" then we need to create multi word index like "Please help" "help here" "here uegently"

Comment: then in this case you may need to index youir field with two different fieldType. One with ShingleFilterFactory and other fieldType will not have it...Then you have to perform the search in those ...

Comment: Indexing is not a problem but when we search with "Please\ help*". Please see the * at the end. Solr is not able to fetch documents which is having only word like "Please" e.g "Please complete work"

Comment: Ok...that is because you have not index it that way so it could search...You need to change the FieldType for your Field...

Comment: Now As you cannot change the FieldType ...you can index a  field by two different fieldTypes ...The new FieldType Will not be having the ShingleFilterFactory...

Comment: If you remove * and search with "please help" then it is returning both document e.g 1) "Please help here" 2) "Please work" so how to do a wild card search by treating each token separately.

Comment: Then everything is working for you...What exactly is your problem...?

Comment: I think you did not read the problem statement properly. Challenge is If there is a sentence like "Please help here". then we need to create index of following tokens "Please" "help" "here" and "Please help" "help here". now when user search for "Please he*" note * at the end then it should match index like "Please help" "Please" "help" (document like "Please work" ) also will be retrieved. But when we do wild card search it is only retrieving document which is starting with "Please he"

Comment: You have to create such indexes in order to get the expected result...What is wrong in creating such index...?

Comment: We already created index with "Please" token but when we try "Please he*" it is not retrieving "Please work" kind of documents.

Comment: It will not work because there is no index with the word he ...you need index the help work into token like he hel help which can be achieved with the help of "NGramTokenizerFactory" or "EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory"...

Comment: do analyse the tokens created and tokens been searched using the solr analysis tool...If any token is not been searched/queried upon.. that means you are not creating any tokens while indexing...The tool is the best thing provided by solr...utilise it...If you still have any doubt ...let me know

Comment: If you search like "Please help" (no * at the end) it search for all "Please help here" and "Please work here" "help is needed" . But if we do a search like "Please help*" (* at the end) then "Please work here " is not coming. So indexing is proper.

Comment: How to mix wild card search and token based search

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a wildcard search, the analysis stage of the query is not invoked. This means that "Please help*" does not go through the Shingle Filter, etc., and therefor doesn't give any hits.

As mentioned in the comments to your question - use an EdgeNgramFilter in the indexing phase instead, and then just submit your query as "Please help". This will then retrieve all documents where the field starts with "Please help", as it will create several versions of the same token (such as "P", "Pl", "Ple", "Plea", "Pleas", "Please", "Please ", "Please H", etc.).

You'll have to adjust the sequence of the filters to match what you need.

You can also use a KeywordTokenizer to get the complete input indexed as a single token (with a LowercaseFilter if you want to), and then use that to match the one, single token against your wildcard search (as no other analysis will need to take place).